# Getting java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server Exception

Tags: java, sockets

Getting **java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server** exception for the following socket creation.I am not using any SOCKS Server & and it is just a stand alone program, this the starting line & getting exception here only.I am using reflection API also.

```
public static String tcpSend(String ip, int port, int timeout, String content)
{
     try
     {
         clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
             .....
         }
      .....
   }
```

Calling from other method like the following:

```
SendReceiveCanMessage.tcpSend("localhost", 8000, 5000,"start");
```

The folling is the complete stacktrace.

> java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.cognizant.vehiclespy.SendReceiveCanMessage.tcpSend(SendReceiveCanMessage.java:19)
>       at Executer.executeTest3_12(Executer.java:672)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.cognizant.controller.SupervisoryControl.execute(SupervisoryControl.java:111)
>       at supervisorycontrol.SupervisoryControlView$ExecuteThread.run(SupervisoryControlView.java:466)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you have the system property 'socksProxyHost' set. Find it and nuke it.